# How to Index excluding the header and footer

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, excel-2016

Is there a way to disregard the header and footer of an indexed data?

I need to dynamically get only the dates only that will be used on another dynamic formula.

My code is not working as `$L$2:$L$4` contains **Holiday** and **END** text. I am planning to use index so that i can only get the dates.

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A2,B2,1,$F$2:$F$4)
```

Holiday column (Column F) is designed that way so that i can insert a row before **END** row adjusting all connected formula such as my ***NetworkDays*** *(screenshot)*.

[image]

EDIT: Adjusted the formula

Comment: Screenshot shows `=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A2,B2,1,$F$1:$F$3)` but you wrote `=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(G3,H3,1,$L$2:$L$4)` can you confirm?

Comment: Also why not convert the `Holiday` range into a table and use it, so it will exclude the header as well gets updated whenever a new holiday is entered in the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the following formula, if you are using `MS365`

---

Using <kbd>DROP( )</kbd> twice.

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A2,B2,1,DROP(DROP($F$1:$F$3,1),-1))
```

---

You can also use the formula in this way, by sorting the range.

Using <kbd>DROP( )</kbd> & <kbd>SORT( )</kbd>

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A2,B2,1,DROP(SORT($F$1:$F$3,,-1),2))
```

---

Or, Using <kbd>TOCOL( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A2,B2,1,TOCOL(--$F$1:$F$3,2))
```

---

You can use <kbd>OFFSET( )</kbd> as well, but note that, since its a  **volatile** function, it does not just **recalculate** anytime something on the sheet changes, it will **recalculate** anytime anything on any open excel workbook changes! Posted as an alternative approach.

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A2,B2,1,OFFSET(F:F,1,,COUNTA(F:F)-2))
```

---

Another alternative approach, which avoids the use of volatile functions:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A2,B2,1,$F$2:INDEX(F:F,MATCH(7^89,F:F)))
```

---

Test cases:

[image]

---

**Note:** Based on one's Excel Version, may need to hit the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode.

---

Please refer the screenshot below.

[image]

---

**Explanation:**

- The number `7` is raised to the power of `8` to create a large number, which is used within <kbd>MATCH( )</kbd> function to search for it, using an approximate match, since it doesn't able to find it, hence returns the last occurrence of the value i.e. `5` which is the last row number of the `Holiday` range.

---

- Since we have got the last position of the `Holiday` range, now we are wrapping it within <kbd>INDEX( )</kbd> to get the date which returns `7/19/2023` as per screenshot.

---

```
INDEX(F:F,MATCH(7^89,F:F))
```

---

- Now referencing `F2` using an **Union** `:` to create a range that starts from cell `F2` and ends till the last value in the column `F`, this creates a dynamic range and ensures whenever a new date is added, which will be used in the <kbd>NETWORKDAYS.INTL( )</kbd> function for the **optional parameter** <kbd>[holidays]</kbd> .

---

```
=$F$2:INDEX(F:F,MATCH(7^89,F:F))
```

---

Lastly, if you don't want to hardcode the cell reference <kbd>F2</kbd> then you could use this as well.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A2,B2,1,INDEX(F:F,2):INDEX(F:F,MATCH(7^89,F:F)))
```

---

One more way, you could try, its only a variant:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A2,B2,1,INDEX(F:F,2):INDEX(F:F,MATCH(2,1/(F:F<>""))-1))
```

---

Comment: Do you have a formula that is also accepted by lower versions of excel? like 2016 and below?

Comment: @Lien0 yes I have added one. Using `OFFSET()`

Comment: @Lien0 please refer i have posted another alternative approach which do not require volatile function, the last one.

Comment: it works! can you help me and explain how this one works? $F$2:INDEX(F:F,MATCH(7^89,F:F)

I dont understand the " : " and " 7^8 "

Comment: @Lien0 Yes sure. I will update in post.

Comment: @Lien0 all updated hope it helps. Good luck =)